# How to get JSON object field value and field values in next array of the same JSON object?

Tags: json, curl, jq

If I have JSON like below returned from my curl response:

```json
{
  "parent": "John Smith",
  "dob": "August 6, 2020",
  "children": [
    {
      "first": "Bob",
      "last": "Smith"
    },
    {
      "first": "John",
      "last": "Smith"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to get field parent in JSON object and first, last fields in nested JSON array above.

I have tried using this `curl` command with `jq` and I can get first and last fields from the children array, but I cannot figure out how to get both parent field *and* first and last fields from same response.

Here is my command to filter first and last fields:

```
curl -G 'http://someapi' | jq '.childrens | .[] | .first, .last'
```

It returns

```
Bob
Smith
John
Smith
```

I would like to get the following:

```
John Smith
Bob
Smith
John
Smith
```

How do I use `jq` to get values for parent field and each child first and last name fields?

Comment: Try  locking the context with parentheses: `.parent, (.children[] | .first, .last)`. Or (as `.first` and `.last` are the only fields present) just iterate over all the fields in the same way: `.parent, .children[][]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never include `.parent` in your result. If you do, you must use parentheses:

```
.parent, (.children[] | .first, .last)
```